# Secure key with PHP?

Tags: javascript, php

I'm new to JS and PHP and currently have a key I need to use in JavaScript; but I don't want the user to be able to view the code and see it.

I tried putting the key in PHP and echoing it for the JS variable that holds the key, but that will just print it out anyways.

How can I use the key in JavaScript without allowing users to view the source?

EDIT: I'm using an API key to get data and use that data in functions.

Comment: Can you show some of your code??

Comment: If the key is secret, the last thing you will want to do is "passing" it to JavaScript.

Comment: "How can I use the key in java script without allowing users to view the source?" You cannot. End of story.

Comment: You never are going to have a secure key if you use that key in JavaScript, is no way to hide it. You need to use php sessions.

Comment: I think Juan just said it. I'm going to try to use the api key in php, get data from there, then send that data to javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Exactly what is it that you are trying to protect against?
Casual use of View Source?
A serious attack against your web app by a skilled user?
Packet sniffing at Starbucks?

Sorry, but I've deleted and rewritten this response a dozen times, with a dozen answers depending on your particular situation. Many different security concepts are at play here. The other posters are all correct, in that you can not conceal Javascript from the user. In fact, you cannot conceal anything that is sent to the user's browser. Obfuscation and sessions can help, but aren't perfect.

That does not mean you can't achieve your security goals.

But we all need to know what you are trying to achieve!

Comment: Alright, so from the tons of people replying I can't do it in Javascript, how would I go through this with php?

The problem is, I'm using an API key and I use javascript functions to get data, etc from the API. How would I use javascript functions while using the key in PHP?

Comment: Don't use JavaScript to get the data from the API; use PHP or other server-side technology.